# Problems with a linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I'm trying to get some specific values organized by months from my database with a Linq query, but I having a little trouble and I don't know why it could be happen.

The data is organized this way:

A **Ticket** has many products, and a **Worker** has many tickets, and a **Shop** has many workers, and an Admin **User** has many shops. It exists a table called Shops_Workers where I can create relations with shops and workers. The *Ticket* has a field with the date that it has created and another field called *Points* that gives an integer value for that ticket. I need to get the sum of all points of all tickets created per worker for all shops that has an user per month.

I'm using EntityFramework and I've tried to make a linq query to get all data, so I've created some DateTime fields to get the months and did subqueries into my linq query, but I don't know if this could work properly.

```
 Int32? admin = getCurrentUser();
 DateTime TmpYear = DateTime.Now;

 var result = (from s in _db.Shops
                      join t in db.Tickets on s.IdShop equals t.IdTicket
                      join sw in db.Shop_Worker on s.IdShop equals sw.IdShop
                      join u in db.Users on sw.IdUser equals u.IdUser
                      where u.IdUser == admin
                      select new {
                          Jan = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Jan.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Feb = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Feb.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Mar = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Mar.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Ap = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Ap.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          May = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.May.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Jun = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Jun.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Jul = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Jul.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Au = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Au.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Sep = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Sep.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Oct = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Oct.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Nov = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Nov.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                          Dec = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Dec.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum(),
                      });
```

I having a System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal error, with message:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues pop out:

```
 Int32? admin = getCurrentUser();
```

Assert that you get an admin user back before attempting to use it in the query, then in the query, use admin.Value.

```
var result = (from s in _db.Shops
                      join t in db.Tickets on s.IdShop equals t.IdTicket
```

Here the Shops and tickets are being joined cross-keyed. (IdShop to IdTicket)
Since it looks like your Shop is mapped with a Tickets collection, these explicit joins are not needed.  Personally I don't use the linq-QL syntax as I find the fluent methods are easier to follow and structure, mixing the two just gets confusing.

What I'd probably look at would be to split the operations, first to get the appropriate data, grouped by month, then transform that into the desired data structure. Linq is great, however trying to do too much in a single expression can make it harder to follow. There may be simplifications to apply, but this should hopefully give you some ideas on how to tackle the transformation.

```
var totalTickets = _db.Shops.Where(s => s.ShopWorkers.Any(sw => sw.IdUser == admin.Value))
    .SelectMany(s => s.Tickets.Where(t => t.SellDate.HasValue && t.SellDate.Value.Year == tmpYear.Year))
    .Select(t => new {Month = t.SellDate.Value.Month, t.Points})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
    .Select(x => new {Month = x.Key, TotalPoints = x.Sum(g => g.Points)).ToList();
```

I'm pulling this from memory, so it may need some tweaking, but the jist is to pull the shops the workers contain the current user, then select all tickets for those shops for the designated year, from that we want the month and the points value. We group by month, then select that group (month) with the sum of the points for that group. You should get a list of every month there were tickets sold. This would not include months where no tickets were sold, so you'd need to Union in the set of zero'd months to get a complete list. From that you should be able to populate a structure with a value for each month as a property.

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is here:

```
Jan = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Jan.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => e.Points).Sum()
```

When you have no data for this condition, SQL will return null, but `Jan` property is not null, so change query like this:

```
Jan = s.Tickets.Where(x => x.SellDate.Value.Month == this.Jan.Month && x.SellDate.Value.Year == TmpYear.Year).Select(e => (int?)e.Points).Sum() ?? 0
```

Comment: It's a great idea, at least now it doesn't give me an error, but I did a query on my database with the Shops table joining tall those tables and adding to the WHERE sentence the January params of the subquery that I coded on my Linq, and I got a response, it's not null. So I thought that I could be doing a bad Linq query, but I don't know where could be the error.